# The term "haystack" in the context of PHP

Tags: php, parameters, terminology

There are a few PHP functions (such as [strstr](http://php.net/strstr), [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) and [strrchr](http://php.net/strrchr))  that accept 
a parameter named `$haystack`. Where does this name come from?

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It comes from the idiom ["needle in a haystack"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/needle_in_a_haystack). The needle is the item you're searching for (in this case the substring, or search string), the haystack is what the needle is located within (in this case the input string).

Edit (pst - to visualize answer):

[image: needle stack]

Comment: It was looking so plain compared to the question :)

Comment: Ahah! I laughed! +1 to both

Comment: The picture is great! In Chinese we have "Finding a needle in the ocean", much harder, I think :).

Answer (score 9):

Finding a needle in a haystack.  You are looking for a substring in a bigger string.

Answer (score 7):

A Needle in a haystack is a figure of speech used to refer to something that is difficult to locate in a much larger space. - wiki